# Mysql add NULL to cols that skipped in insert and that col is unique

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to add the flowing `insert`:

```
INSERT INTO `user` 
(`name`, `family`, `status`, `mobile`,  `ip`, `lastIp`, `seenTime`, `createTime`, `updateTime`) 
VALUES 
('Mehdi Abbasi', NULL, 4, '989197659980',  '149.154.167.210', '149.154.167.210', 1507650436, 1507650436, 1507650436)
```

And in database i have this:

[image: Database values]

Null value for family save as `null` in database and there is no problem about that but skipped cols like `email` filled by `NULL` and when trying to add another user whiteout  email get duplicate key error from database.

> Note: `email` field has unique key.

This problem is strange because it's worked in the past.

Table schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `passwordResetToken` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `family` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` smallint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `ip` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastIp` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `seenTime` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updateTime` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createTime` int(20) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;


--
-- Indexes for table `user`
--
ALTER TABLE `user`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `mobile` (`mobile`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `passwordResetToken` (`passwordResetToken`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `user`
--
ALTER TABLE `user`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=6;
```

For example `passwordResetToken` and  `email` give `NULL` but `family` not.
Value in `family` col make no problem but `email` make.

Comment: please, add the create code of the table to the question.

Comment: could you add the table schema?

Comment: As `NULL` is not equal to, nor not inequal to `NULL`, uniqueness constraints do not apply.

Comment: @IvoP, I am edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely answer is that you created the `user.email` column as `NOT NULL` with a default value.

If you truly want to have a unique index on the `user.email` column and allow multiple rows without an `email` value, then you need to alter your table to make the `user.email` column allow `NULL` values.

Here's an example using your schema to show how you can successfully add multiple rows with `NULL` `email` values despite the unique index:

```
mysql > CREATE TABLE `user` (
    ->   `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    ->   `password` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    ->   `passwordResetToken` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `name` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    ->   `family` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `email` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `mobile` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `status` smallint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    ->   `ip` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `lastIp` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `seenTime` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `updateTime` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `createTime` int(20) DEFAULT NULL
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql > alter table user add unique index email (email);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql > insert into user (id,password,name) values (1,'foo','foo');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

mysql > insert into user (id,password,name) values (2,'foo','foo');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql [localhost] {msandbox} (test) > select * from user;
+----+----------+--------------------+------+--------+-------+--------+--------+------+--------+----------+------------+------------+
| id | password | passwordResetToken | name | family | email | mobile | status | ip   | lastIp | seenTime | updateTime | createTime |
+----+----------+--------------------+------+--------+-------+--------+--------+------+--------+----------+------------+------------+
|  1 | foo      | NULL               | foo  | NULL   | NULL  | NULL   |      1 | NULL | NULL   |     NULL |       NULL |       NULL |
|  2 | foo      | NULL               | foo  | NULL   | NULL  | NULL   |      1 | NULL | NULL   |     NULL |       NULL |       NULL |
+----+----------+--------------------+------+--------+-------+--------+--------+------+--------+----------+------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I allowed `email` accept null but its make duplicate index problem.

Comment: Yes i want absolutely this but i'm wondered why mysql not working correct and make this problem.

Comment: @Amin MySQL allows multiple NULL values in a unique index. What version of MySQL are you using? Can you post your _actual_ `CREATE TABLE` statement? The one you posted does not have a unique index, so its you are getting duplicate key errors then that is not the right `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolve my problem by doping database and create it again and insert backup rows to that.

I don't know why this problem happens at all.

Answer (score -1):

The cause of your problem is in two things:

1) you do allow NULL values inserted for the `email`. 
That alone is no reason for an error, as you can see with the column `Family` not having any problems.

2) you on the other hand require the column `email` to have unique values.
And that is contracticting with allowing null values. 
I am not sure if you were able to insert at least 1 record with NULL in `email`, but multiple inserts with NULL will trigger an error on those "values"  being duplicates.

So: don't let your application insert null into `email`

Comment: I inserted multi record by email null whit this schema.